# Trying to understand block alignment

Tags: block-editor

I am having trouble understanding how the alignment works in Gutenberg. Here I have 2 blocks that are almost identical:

```html
<!-- wp:group { "layout":{ "type":"constrained" } } -->
<div class="wp-block-group">

    <!-- wp:group { "align":"wide" } -->
    <div class="wp-block-group alignwide">
        <!-- wp:site-title {"level":0} /-->
    </div>
    <!-- /wp:group -->

    <!-- wp:group -->
    <div class="wp-block-group alignwide">
        <!-- wp:site-title {"level":0} /-->
    </div>
    <!-- /wp:group -->

</div>
<!-- /wp:group -->
```

The only difference between them is `{"align":"wide"}`. But they both seem to look exactly the same. Both use the "wide alignment", which makes sense, since I set it up manually in the "class" attribute. So what is the point of adding it also in `wp:group`?

Comment: Skipping the inline align attribute `{"align":"wide"}`,  when writing the block manually, will make the block's alignment control out of sync in the visual editor, compared to the HTML wide alignment class.

Comment: Then let me ask it the other way around.

If I need to write the attribute explicitly, why do I need to also add the class `alignwide` manually? Shouldn't it be automatically added?

The outer `wp:group` adds a class `is-layout-constrained` class automatically to the `<div>` without me having to write it manually.